# IOS - NativeScript - CoAp - Cannot connect to Link-local ipV6 address - even i have permission

Tags: ios, nativescript-angular, coap, ios-permissions, link-local

I have a NativeScrpt app, and I try to comionicate on CoAP (Constrained Application Protocol) via local wifi network.
ipV4 works well, and in Android, all work well too (so, the address itself is right).

But, on the IOS side, I cannot connect to devices via the ipV6 Link-local address.

In my info.plist I have this permissions:
NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription
NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription

and in the iPhone itself I can see the app has permission.

The format of my ipV6 is:'fe80::eeee:5%en0'
I try to test my app on ios 15.4, iPhone 13. minimum version to build - ios 11.

The App sends the request but does not receive any response.
For the CoAp client in the app I used "cocaAsyncSocket" (GCDAsyncUdpSocket) and [SwiftCoAP](https://github.com/stuffrabbit/SwiftCoAP)

I try to connect anuder device, set maby capabilities in the xCode and more...